# Any canon back story for Majel Barrett’s Number One?

Tags: star-trek

This [very nice post](http://intergalacticexplorer.tumblr.com/post/78970968378/what-if-tos-had-900-more-central-female) in celebration of "Intergalactic" Women's Day serves to celebrate the many strong female characters in Star Trek, down to Rahda.

And I realized that I don't think there's any name, back-story or any detail at all for the original Number One in the pilot, The Cage. We assume she's alien, and has a similar lack of emotion that we later saw in Spock in TOS, but other than that, pfft.

Has there been no additional material done for the Pike Years that filled her history out a bit? Seems odd for them to not do SOMETHING.

Comment: you mean information other than this extensive wiki? http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Number_One

Comment: Or here on Wikipedia; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_One_(Star_Trek)

Comment: I never thought of her as lacking emotion or anything but human.

Comment: You didn't mention what you meant by 'canon'.  If you want to read books, read the very recently released [Legacies series](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Legacies).  It doesn't add a lot of back story, but it does add some.  It also features her pretty heavily in the current events of the series.

Comment: Non-canon... Peter David's novel "The Rift".

Comment: Not a huge spoiler, but *ST: Discovery* ended Season 1 with the Pike Enterprise sending a distress signal. You might get a canon answer when Season 2 starts

Answer (score 3):

In 2016, Pocket Books published the [Legacies](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Legacies) series.
It is all about Number One and who exactly she is.

She is described as being a human born and raised on the planet Illyria.
The seemingly designation "Number One" is actually her name. She is called Una because her Illyrian name is considered unpronounceable by outsiders and was always top of her class thus earning the nickname Number One.

She served on a number of ships eventually receiving her own command with the USS Yorktown.

Far more can be found here: [Number One on memory-beta](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Number_One).
However, be careful, because it contains a lot of spoilers; especially about the aforementioned Legacies series.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! While this may answer the question it would be a lot better if you included some relevant information into your answer. For example, a bit of the major points of the back story (if short enough) etc.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Problem is that I didn't want to include spoilers.

Comment: You can hide spoilers with the markdown `>!` but make sure all of the answer isn't hidden... only hide the relevant parts.